# Python convert hex string to byte value

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary

I have this string of bytes:

```
output1 = 'fef00a01'
```

and I am trying to convert it to bytes:

```
output2 = b'\xfe\xf0\n\x01'
```

This does not satisfies the condition:

```
output1 == output2 # <--- returns False
```

How can I make it to return True?

Comment: ```output1``` is of type ```string``` and ```output2``` is of type ```bytes```. How can you expect them to be equal ? Also, Could you elaborate what do you want to achieve.

Comment: I am trying to convert output1 to output2

Comment: You coud use ```bytes()``` function to convert ```string``` to ```bytes``` in Python. BTW what is the encoding of ```output2``` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it is simple:

```
>>> bytes.fromhex(output1) 
b'\xfe\xf0\n\x01'
```

Answer (score 0):

`outpu1` is a string of characters representing a hex value. Your comparison will always yield `false` without some sort of conversion (they’re two different objects underneath). It’s akin to testing `'123' == 123`.

Basically, you need to convert that string to bytes before comparing. Use something like `binascii` to convert the hex string into actual bytes like so:

```
import binascii

output1 = binascii.unhexlify('fef00a01')
```

Comment: How can I do it without external packages?